# If I book two flights with Sichuan Airlines, and miss the second because the first is delayed, can I reschedule for free?

Tags: air-travel, china, missed-flights, connecting-flights

I arrive at Chengdu at 5:50 AM (this flight is booked with Sichuan Airlines) and want to go straight on to Shanghai (this flight is not yet booked). There's a flight at 7:40 AM, with the same airline.

Of course, if the first flight (from Melbourne) is delayed, I'll probably miss the second.

If that happens, does anyone know if I can then reschedule for free?

Comment: do you buy two different tickets?

Comment: You should try the airlines WeChat http://www.sichuanair.com/3uair/ibe/common/homeRedirect.do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless your ticket class permits rescheduling for free (unlikely unless you've booked a more expensive flexible fare class), because these flights will be on two separate tickets, you are owed no protection if the first flight is delayed.

Your options:

- Book the second flight with a very long delay (a few hours) to maximize the odds of you arriving on time.
- Modify the original booking to add the flight connection to the second city.  The airline will then owe you a guarantee of passage to the second city, if you miss the second flight due to the first being delayed.
- Book the second ticket as a flexible ticket, so that if it is apparent you will be late, you can reschedule it for little or no cost.

You could possibly use a lower fare class on the second ticket, but you will have to pay a fee to reschedule the flight, and if you don't do so prior to the departure of your second flight, you may end up forfeiting the entire fare.